# Android view background colored with transparent element

Tags: android, view, background, transparent, shapes

We can easily make a background transparent & colored element with Shape like this :

- Color bleue : Solid color
- white/gray square : transparent

[image]

```
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners 
        android:radius="20dp"/>
    <solid 
        android:color="#1f93ed" />
</shape>
```

But how can i do a view background with colored back and transparent element like this :

[image]

as if the background color was holed by form...
Any idea?

Comment: What color will the transparent circle will take? As it will automatically display the background color of its parent.

Comment: The color set in the background of the parent layout or else the theme.

Comment: yes, in the images, transparent must display parent layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw yourself colored area with override of onDraw in custom drawable or view.

For exemple, in this code i draw four "corner outline" :

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        drawCorner(cornerSizeInPixel, canvas, Color.GREEN));
    }

    private void drawCorner(int size, Canvas canvas, int color)
    {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        // top left
        Path p = new Path();
        p.moveTo(0, 0);
        p.lineTo(size, 0);
        p.arcTo(new RectF(0, 0, size, size), 180, 90, true);
        p.lineTo(0, 0);
        canvas.drawPath(p, paint);  

        // bottom left
        int h = canvas.getHeight();
        p = new Path();
        p.moveTo(0, h);
        p.lineTo(size, h);
        p.arcTo(new RectF(0, h - size, size, h), 90, 90, true);
        p.lineTo(0, h);
        canvas.drawPath(p, paint);

        // top right
        int w = canvas.getWidth();
        p = new Path();
        p.moveTo(w, 0);
        p.lineTo(w - size, 0);
        p.arcTo(new RectF(w - size, 0, w, size), 270, 90, true);
        p.lineTo(w, 0);
        canvas.drawPath(p, paint);  

        // bottom right
        p = new Path();
        p.moveTo(w, h);
        p.lineTo(w - size, h);
        p.arcTo(new RectF(w - size, h - size, w, h), 0, 90, true);
        p.lineTo(w, h);
        canvas.drawPath(p, paint);  
    }
```

Result: 4 green form in every corner of the image, which together draw a rounded rectangle really transparent

Answer (score 0):

option 1: use normal .png file

option 2: create a custom Drawable by extending ShapeDrawable class

Answer (score -1):

Replace `android:color="#1f93ed"` with `android:color="@android:color/transparent` and set the background to the Blue colour

Comment: How can you set two backgrounds on a single view? As shape itself will be set as background. Even if you set the middle circle as transparent it will display the background color being transparent.

Comment: You will need to take 2 views the transparent view and background view. Or else the background of the parent layout or the theme will be visible.

Comment: if you put the transparent shape over a colored view, you will see the colored view inside shape. This's the problem.

Comment: Beside the colored view or on the colored view?

Comment: There is no background element of a drawable.  You can only set the color of the shape.  Ie, your suggestion: "set the background to the Blue colour" is no possible.  If this was possible, I would be very, very happy.